# importAnnotCommand returning undefined

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I am trying to import freehand annotations using the xfdf format with the importAnnotCommand() method but I get a return value of undefined sometimes, I am generating these strings using the getAnnotCommand() method.

The xfdf string is generated by the getAnnotCommand() method and I log the string to the console, to make sure it looks right. The annotations only reliably load on the first two pages of a document.

import code, the backlog contains the annotations that fail to load:

```js
        const  backlog = docModel.prototype.annots[webviewer.id].backlog
        const  backup = docModel.prototype.annots[webviewer.id].backup
        let annots = annotationManager.importAnnotations(backup)
        annotationManager.drawAnnotationsFromList(annots)
        let tmp = [];
        if (Array.isArray(backlog)) {
          while(backlog.length > 0) {
            const backlogObj = backlog.pop()
            if (backlogObj.xfdf) {
              const xfdf = backlogObj.xfdf
              const annot = annotationManager.importAnnotCommand(xfdf)[0]
              if (annot === undefined) {
                tmp.push(backlogObj)
              } else {
              }
              console.log('loading annot:',annot,'\nxfdf:',xfdf)
            } else if(backlogObj.hide) {
              annotationManager.hideAnnotation(annotationManager.getAnnotationById(backlogObj.id))
            }
          }
        docModel.prototype.annots[webviewer.id].backlog = tmp
```

example xfdf that fails:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields />
<add><ink page="1" rect="302.917853,630.040373,348.65741,715.919953" color="#D5252E" flags="print" name="00d08e8b-01b7-e6d2-2f88-35890f19f16c" title="Guest" subject="Free hand" date="D:20190522154716-04'00'" width="4.2" creationdate="D:20190522154714-04'00'"><inklist><gesture>317.39,711.72;317.39,711.72;317.39,711.72;317.39,711.72;318.32,711.72;320.19,711.72;322.05,711.72;323.92,711.72;325.79,711.72;327.65,710.79;328.59,710.79;329.52,710.79;330.46,709.85;331.39,708.92;332.32,707.05;333.26,704.25;334.19,701.45;334.19,698.65;334.19,694.92;334.19,692.12;333.26,688.38;331.39,685.58;329.52,682.78;328.59,679.98;325.79,675.31;322.05,671.58;318.32,666.91;314.59,661.31;311.79,656.64;309.92,653.84;308.05,650.11;308.05,647.31;307.12,644.51;307.12,642.64;308.05,640.77;308.05,639.84;308.98,638.91;309.92,637.97;310.85,637.04;312.72,636.11;315.52,635.17;318.32,635.17;322.99,634.24;327.65,634.24;331.39,634.24;335.12,634.24;337.92,634.24;341.66,634.24;343.52,634.24;344.46,634.24;344.46,634.24</gesture></inklist></ink></add>
<modify />
<delete />
</xfdf>
```

example xfdf that works:

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields />
<add><ink page="0" rect="325.321587,653.377596,335.588565,746.725088" color="#D5252E" flags="print" name="849c13ac-c0e6-e639-8d50-0c6b6639a3e2" title="Guest" subject="Free hand" date="D:20190522154712-04'00'" width="4.2" creationdate="D:20190522154710-04'00'"><inklist><gesture>329.52,742.53;330.46,742.53;330.46,741.59;330.46,739.72;330.46,737.86;330.46,733.19;330.46,726.66;331.39,717.32;331.39,707.99;331.39,698.65;331.39,692.12;331.39,674.38;331.39,667.85;331.39,663.18;331.39,661.31;331.39,659.44;331.39,658.51;331.39,657.58;331.39,657.58</gesture></inklist></ink></add>
<modify />
<delete />
</xfdf>
```

the following is an error message I receive, but it doesn't go off every time I get undefined back

```
CoreControls.js:989 exportAnnotations was called before all annotations were loaded.
Gq  @   CoreControls.js:989
(anonymous) @   CoreControls.js:1479
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   CoreControls.js:1479
dispatch    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
trigger @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
triggerHandler  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
applyWithArgs   @   CoreControls.js:92
trigger @   CoreControls.js:92
Tg  @   CoreControls.js:978
HE  @   CoreControls.js:1014
Yw  @   CoreControls.js:1012
uo  @   CoreControls.js:1011
uo  @   CoreControls.js:990
updateAnnotList @   my_file.js:224
```

Note, line 224 in my code is `const annot = annotationManager.importAnnotCommand(xfdf)[0]` from above

I expect that importAnnotCommand(xfdf) would return a list of annotations imported, but sometimes it fails and just returns undefined.

Comment: The failing annotating is for the 2nd page of a PDF. When it fails to load, does the opened/target PDF have at least 2 pages?

Comment: Also, can you add any related errors/warnings from the javascript console to your question.

Comment: yes, the document has 9 pages, the xfdf string was generated from this document

Comment: @Ryan I included some more console logs for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CoreControls.js:989 exportAnnotations was called before all annotations were loaded.
```

It appears you are trying to export to soon. Annotations are loaded after the document is initially loaded, and may take a while if there are many.

You want to wait for this event.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation-events#annotationsloaded

Before you do anything with the document though, you need to wait for the documentLoaded event.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/webviewer-events/#documentviewerdocumentloaded

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out tomorrow at work, currently this is all executed after waiting for the document to load, but I can try swapping it to waiting for that event

Comment: The `annotationsLoaded`event seems to be firing before all the annotations are loaded, then firing a second time. I'm getting no errors on the second time and when it fires the first time, some annotations are still imported as undefined, all of them load when it fires the second time.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear if this question is resolved, or not, for you? If this is still an issue? If so, please update your question with the latest state.

Comment: I've changed the implementation to load multiple things in different webviewers now instead of moving one around and constantly reusing it, so there is no longer an issue that this stuff.